# OpenGL keyboard input

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I'am trying to implement some key-input's to my application. For example moving my camera. I use lwjgl. So i tried this :

```
if(key == GLFW_KEY_A && action == GLFW_PRESS){
                    camera.translate(new Vector3f(+0.5f,0,-0.5f));
                }
```

The Problem is now, that this is only executed one time, which  means i cant move my camera by holding this key.

So i tried something like this :

```
if(key == GLFW_KEY_D && action == GLFW_PRESS){

                    while(action != GLFW_RELEASE){
                        a.getView().translate(new Vector3f(-0.5f,0,+0.5f));

                    }   
                }
```

which crashes my application because of an infinity loop.

Mabe somebody can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with GLFW in particular but found `GLFW_REPEAT` which might be what you're looking for (the documentation of it was lacking to say the least).

If that doesn't work it's not uncommon to use shadow registers for keyboard input, where you update the state of every key of interest whenever they occur. Then you can just provide yourself with a `bool keyIsDown(keytype_t key);` function that you can poll each frame.

Comment: Seems `int glfwGetKey(GLFWwindow *window, int key);` could be of interest too.

Comment: this doesnt work for me , still thanks for the answer

Comment: it works when i save the state of my keyborad inputs in an boolean array, thx for the idea